# React native draggable flatlist not draggable

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-draggable-flatlist

I tried implementing react-native-draggable-flatlist to my project, but I'm not able to drag the elements. I am able to "pick them" (They get bigger if I press them), but I can't move them to another position.

I had this problem before and found a working soloution in a GitHub issue, but as it seems, MainActivity.java has changed in some version and I don't know how to correctly upgrade it.

The [soloution](https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist/issues/159#issuecomment-719597386) I found:
[image]

When I add the @Override for the ReactActivityDelegate, my App crashes after the build.
I noticed that my MainActivity.java looks a little bit different, it seems like the ActivityDelegate is Managed through a class called MainActivityDelegate which extends ReactActivityDelegate:

```
public static class MainActivityDelegate extends ReactActivityDelegate {
public MainActivityDelegate(ReactActivity activity, String mainComponentName) {
  super(activity, mainComponentName);
}

@Override
protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
  ReactRootView reactRootView = new ReactRootView(getContext());
  // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
  reactRootView.setIsFabric(BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED);
  return reactRootView;
}
}
```

It seems like I have to change something here to achieve the same result, but I don't really know what.

**EDIT:**
According to the [RNGH docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/guides/migrating-off-rnghenabledroot) you shouldn't change your MainActivity.java that way anymore and wrap your whole App into a GestureHandlerRootView. Some Libaries like react-native-navigation do this by default (in my case). BEcause of that (I think) my App gets completely grey when I use a GestureHandlerRootView. If I don't addd it myself, so I use the one from neavigaion, I still can't drag the items in my list.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by wrapping my screen component in a GestureHandlerRootView